# How to have aliases with nodejs import

Tags: node.js, import, alias, require

I have a project using node.js v16, and more and more npm libs are not anymore compatible with require, and need to be used with import.

Until now i was using package.json to have my root directory as alias

```
  // package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "~src": "file:.",
  }
```

And in my source code

```
const someCode = require('~src/absolute/path/someCode');
```

This is not working with import, and with tests i made, i haven't found any solution to make it works with import.

Have you already met that kind of problem ? And found a solution about it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the preferred way to alias folders in current versions of Node is using [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports).

For example, you could alias your root folder as `#src` (import mappings must always start with `#`). To do so, add the following imports section in your package.json:

```json
"imports": {
  "#src/*": "./*.js"
}
```

Now, supposing you have a file `some/path/someCode.js` in your package, you could import it like this:

```js
import someCode from '#src/some/path/someCode';
```

You can also map subfolders with the same syntax:

```js
"imports": {
  "#src/*": "./*.js",
  "#somepath/*": "./some/path/*.js"
}
```

And in the importing file:

```js
import someCode from '#somepath/someCode';
```

Comment: Nice thank you for your answer, i will give it a try tomorrow :)

Comment: This is working fine. I'm a bit disappointed with 'index.js' not managed automatically, but seems due to ( https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions )
This is a bit of topic, but do you have any idea on how to enforce automatic '.js / index.js' management ?

Comment: I found an answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159533/es6-ecmascript-2015-modules-import-index-js

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no way for import names to match multiple files, like require can do by appending ".js", ".json", "/index.js", [etc.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together)

Comment: For people searching to auto import .js  .json /index.js i created a lib compatible with Node.js 19+ https://www.npmjs.com/package/specifier-resolution-node

Answer (score 3):

note that if you are using typescript, you'll have to update your tsconfig as well. Let's say you want to use `@helpers/whatever` instead of `../../../helpers/whatever`

```json
"baseUrl": "src", # or whatever your base directory is
"paths": {
   "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
},
```

And if you are using jest, you will also need to update your jest config

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@helpers/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/helpers/$1',
},
```